# Remove empty element but keep zeros as values

Tags: python, list

I have a list as follows:

```
lst = [-1.33, '', -1.33, -1.33 -2.62, 0, -2.66, 1.41, 0, 0, 1.40, '',  1.37, 0]
```

where there are two empty elements `''` in the list with several zeroes and float numbers.

How can I remove the empty elements but keep the zeroes? as follows...

```
lst2 = [-1.33, -1.33, -1.33 -2.62, 0, -2.66, 1.41, 0, 0, 1.40, 1.37, 0]
```

I have tried the following:

```
lst2 = filter(None, lst)
```

and

```
lst2 = [x for x in lst if x if isinstance(x,str) == False]
```

but, it removes the zeroes as well.

I know floats return 12 decimal places, please ignore for example purposes.

Any advice?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi all, forgot to add that, the empty string might be several spaces. i.e.`''` , `' '`, `'   '`.

Comment: To account for spaces, just do x.strip() != ''

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not simply remove all `''` ?

```
>>> lst2 = [x for x in lst if x != '']
>>> lst2
[-1.33, -1.33, -3.95, 0, -2.66, 1.41, 0, 0, 1.4, 1.37, 0]
>>>
```

or you could keep only floats and ints:

```
>>> [x for x in lst if isinstance(x, (float, int))]
[-1.33, -1.33, -3.95, 0, -2.66, 1.41, 0, 0, 1.4, 1.37, 0]

# or a bit fancier
>>> import numbers
>>> [x for x in lst if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]
[-1.33, -1.33, -3.95, 0, -2.66, 1.41, 0, 0, 1.4, 1.37, 0]
```

Comment: This will definitely work. Just about to answer with this myself.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at what you have

```
lst2 = [x for x in lst 
if x 
if isinstance(x,str) == False]
```

What do you have the `if x` in there for?

Also, never never never use `== False` and `== True`

Use `not isinstance(x, str)`

So you should have

```
   lst2 = [x for x in lst if isinstance(x, str)]
```

Or as other have suggested

```
lst2 = [x for x in lst if x != '']
```

Since your list has both strings and numbers in it, I suspect that it'll be easier to deal this at the point that you created this list. Of course, without seeing that I can't be certain or tell you how to fix it.

Comment: argh.. the `if x` was a typo. wrote spontatenously than cut and paste. works now! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = [x for x in lst if x != '']
>>> l
[-1.3300000000000001, -1.3300000000000001, -3.9500000000000002, 0, -2.6600000000000001, 1.4099999999999999, 0, 0, 1.3999999999999999, 1.3700000000000001, 0]
```

Seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the filter function is the beautiful way to do what you want.

```
lst = [-1.33, '', -1.33, -1.33 -2.62, 0, -2.66, 1.41, 0, 0, 1.40, '',  1.37, 0]
lst2 = filter(lambda x: x != '', lst)
print lst2
```

Ouput:

```
[-1.33, -1.33, -3.95, 0, -2.66, 1.41, 0, 0, 1.37, 1.37, 0]
```

As you can read [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) :

```
filter(function, iterable)
```

equals

```
[item for item in iterable if function(item)]
```